# i want to count the number of user login at account for 5 mins,10mins at database

Tags: mysql

[image]

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(
MINUTE , login, logout ) - ( 60 * TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , login, logout ) ) AS minutes
FROM page_views
```

I tried this query i got answer but i need total counts whom login for 5 mins,10 mins like that

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding of your question is correct, this query should work:

```
SELECT count(*) TIMESTAMPDIFF(
MINUTE , login, logout ) - ( 60 * TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , login, logout ) ) AS minutes
FROM page_views 
group by TIMESTAMPDIFF(
MINUTE , login, logout ) - ( 60 * TIMESTAMPDIFF( HOUR , login, logout ) ) AS minutes
```